# IIS with PHP/MariaDB is very slow

Tags: php, mariadb

When I call a page only with PHP everything is very fast.
As soon as I call a database connection, the connection is very slow (several seconds).

I have already disabled IPv6 and changed the access from localhost to 127.0.0.1.
Also I have already adjusted various settings in the my.ini (What I found here)

```
bind-address = *
default-storage-engine=INNODB
innodb_log_file_size=2G
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
max_connection=2000
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
long_query_time=1
key_buffer_size = 20M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12G
table_open_cache = 3000
query_cache_size = 0
```

What else could I try?

Comment: Please explain what exactly is slow. Are you performing a query on the database or is establishing the connection slow?

Comment: I have add informations in first post

Comment: sorry, but in your post I cannot find any information regarding my question. question 1: what exactly is slow - establishing the connection or executing statements? question 2: did you check if the connection has been established successfully?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. 1. I think the connection setup since the queries are ok so far. Can I test this somehow? 2. Yes. I can also install e.g. a CMS or a forum and it works. But the page load is very slow (sometimes 2 - 5 seconds)

Comment: What does the slowlog say is the slowest query?

Comment: The slowlog is empty. a benchmark in a forum software is under 0.5s